# Slow Large Innodb DB Import into Amazon RDS using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

OK
I am experimenting with Amazon RDS and am having heaps of trouble loading an InnoDB database using mysqldump in a timely manner.

I am trying to get my local DB to the cloud.

Using

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --opt -u root > file.sql
```

I can get a dump (~1.5GB) in around 3 minutes to my local file.
The database is about 4G but mysqldump produces an sql file about 1.5G

When I use

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u XXXX -pXXXX DBNAME --compress --single-transaction --quick  --opt --order-by-primary| mysql --host=AMAZONHOSTNAME --user=username --password DBNAME
```

it takes forever - I estimate based on the rate its going it will take 5 hours.

In terms of my bandwidth speed, on www.speedtest.net I get an upload speed of 0.67Mbps.

I cannot understand why its taking so long.
I am :
a) compressing the stream
b) have all the options that the forums seems to require as well as the Amazon docs
c) have a LARGE instance on Amazon RDS.

Can anyone help me here? Is there any way to improve the speed?

Comment: You're bound by RDS's IOPS. If you're not using provisioned RDS, then you probably "rolled" horrible hardware and you're capped at 300ish IOPS (that's the number I got the last time I played with RDS). Nothing much you can do, except get the provisioned RDS which guarantees 10k IOPS.

Comment: I dont think thats right - I just rechecked my bandwidth calculation - 1.5GB at 0.67 Megabits per second (8 megabits per megabyte) will take 1500*8/0.67 = 17,910 seconds or /60 or 4.9 hours, which is what I am experiencing. I think its my bandwidth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed it, or at least improved the speed by a large amount.

I added --compress to the REMOTE side of the mysqldump command

ie this

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u XXXX -pXXXX DBNAME --compress --single-transaction --quick  --opt --order-by-primary| mysql --host=AMAZONHOSTNAME --user=username --password DBNAM
```

became this

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u XXXX -pXXXX DBNAME --compress --single-transaction --quick  --opt --order-by-primary| mysql --compress --host=AMAZONHOSTNAME --user=username --password DBNAM
```

The data transfer rate (as measured by the increasing size of my remote database) went from about 13MB per minute to about 73MB per minute.